# Small Bootstrap Modal Inside of a Larger Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a modal inside of a modal.  However the height of the first modal is much greater than the second modal.  So when I open the first modal the height is correct.  however when the second modal opens.  It can scroll past the second modal and scrolls on the first modal.

I want to either stop the scrolling or set the height of the modal without disrupting the content of the first modal.  I've tried setting the overflow of the first modal to hidden which stops the scrolling on the first modal from moving but it will still scroll though the height.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you provide your codes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Bootstrap Modal Plugin` to archive that functionality because apparently Bootstrap doesn't have that feature: Check out the [examples](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap [does not support multiple open modals](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing
>   more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

Not only is it not technically supported out of the box, two modals would look ugly. I recommend closing the first modal on whatever action opens the second modal.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to open Small Bootstrap Modal Inside of a Larger Bootstrap Modal
See This

http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html